# Doctrine 2 Events

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I'm trying to setup an event trigger in Doctrine, so that i can have access to the querybuilder done atm.

I've setup in my module the listener:

```
$doctrineEventManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.eventmanager.default_orm');

$doctrineEventManager->addEventListener('example', function($eventArgs) {
                die("event");
     });
```

And in my repository:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent('example', $query);
```

But it seems i'm doing something wrong or missing somehting, because its not working..

I cant find a way to implement this simple routine..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define a class with the event function you need, so that's called automatically.

```
$doctrineEventManager->addEventListener('example', new ExampleEvent());
```

Then, create ExampleEvent class and add "example" function:

```
<?php
class ExampleEvent {
        public function example($eventArgs) {
                // do whatever you want..
        }
}
```

After, you just need to trigger the event, in your repo:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent('example', $eventArgs);
```

I did not try, but it will be something like this, in a nutshell.